# 20.04 no sound from line-in

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I don't get any sound from 'line-in' When I load 'pulse audio volume control' it shows that 'line in' is plugged in I had a 3.5mm stereo cable connected from phone headphone jack to pc blue 'line in' the phone is playing a song but 'line in' isn't pickin it up It works when I remove the cable from the computer and plug it into my bluetooth party speaker, which isn't a computer Why is the party speaker better at this task than a computer Is it complicated to get it working on ubuntu?

Comment: You didn't mention which Ubuntu 20.04 system you're using (*Desktop & Server have different kernel stack defaults which may make a difference*). I have hardware that has both front & rear jacks, with the rear ports being disconnected when something is plugged into the front (or vice-versa). On some hardware this is done by the hardware itself & out of the control of the software/OS running  (ie. plug input into the front & output from the back & neither may work as box logic will decide which will be used & they'll both be front/back which may not align with your connections)

Comment: I found the solution to the problem I had to run `load-module module-loopback`

Answer (score 0):

I had to run:

```
load-module module-loopback
```